# Shared Component in Lazy Modules Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a problem and I don't know what I'm not seeing.

I have equis Modules

ComponentsHomeModule, a file where I have a component that I would like to share

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ElementComponent } from './element/element.component';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [ElementComponent],
  exports: [ElementComponent],
})
export class ComponentsHomeModule {}
```

In this case, the component is ElementComponent, that's the component I want to share.

Then I have my ElementsModule where I want to use the ElementComponent

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { ElementsRoutingModule } from './elements-routing.module';
import { ElementsComponent } from './elements.component';
import { ComponentsHomeModule } from '../../components/components-home.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, ComponentsHomeModule, ElementsRoutingModule],
  declarations: [ElementsComponent],
})
export class ElementsModule {}
```

an then inside the ElementsComponent I'm trying to render the ElementComponent but when I make in my html

```
ElementsComponent html:
<app-element></app-element>
```

In the console I see the error of

```
ERROR in src/app/home/pages/elements/elements.component.html:15:7 - error TS8001: 'app-element' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-element' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module
```

I don't know where is the error because if I have my component imported and exported into the ComponentsHomeModule and then I'm importing that module all should work.

By the way I tried with import the ComponentsHomeModule into the App.Module and nothing and the Module where I'm using the ComponentsHomeModule is used in a lazy load:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { ElementsRoutingModule } from './pages/elements/elements-routing.module';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'elements',
      },
      {
        path: 'elements',
        loadChildren: () => ElementsRoutingModule,
      }
    ],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class HomeRoutingModule {}
```

SOLVED::

The problem was in the importing of the lazy loading.

I was importing the RoutingMoudule instead of only the module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { ElementsModule } from './pages/elements/elements.module';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'elements',
      },
      {
        path: 'elements',
        loadChildren: () => ElementsModule,
      }
    ],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class HomeRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: post code for `ElementComponent`

Answer (score 1):

Your `ElementsComponent` is part of `ElementsModule`, so if you want to use `ElementsComponent` in `ComponentsHomeModule` then you need to exports `ElementsComponent` form `ElementsModule`, not from `ComponentsHomeModule`.